# Finite index subgroup of HNN extension

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-actions, trees

Let $GX$ be a tree group (a right-angled Artin group such that the graph is a tree), such that not all the subgroups of $GX$ are necessarily RAAGs, so the length of the tree is greater or equal than $4$.

Then, $GX= A\ast_{C} B$, where $C=\langle c \rangle$ is a cyclic group. Let $t$ be an hyperbolic element in $GX$. It is known that there is a finite index subgroup $M$ such that $M= B \ast_{C\cap M} \langle t \rangle$ ($M$ is an HNN extension). Hence, the generators of $M$ are the generators of  $$G, (M\cap A), (M\cap B), (M\cap A^g), (M \cap B^g), \cdots, \{ t \}$$ and the relations tell me (apart from the relations in the groups $G,\dots, M\cap B^g$) that $t^{-1}s_{1}t=s_{2}$ where $s_{1}$ is an element in a cyclic edge group. So up to conjugacy, I may assume that $s_{1}$ is $c^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, I would like to find a finite index subgroup in $M$ such that $s_{1}^m$ is a generator and $s_{1}$ is not in the subgroup. Since $s_{1}$ lies in the edge group, is it enough to find a finite index subgroup in $A$ with that property?

Comment: The group$G$ that you have defined there is a free group on the generators $t,s_1,s_3,\ldots$, so there are certainly  subgroups of index $m$ containing $s_1^m$.

Comment: @DerekHolt sorry, I should have written it correctly. It is possible for the $s_{i}$ to have relations between them, I wanted to say that $t$ only acts on $s_{1}$.

Comment: I think you need to make it clearer exactly what you are trying to achieve. It is unlikely that you can say very much without further assumptions.

Comment: The group is now just the free product of $\langle t\rangle$ with $\langle s_2,\dots,s_n\mid R\rangle$ with $s_1$ defined as $ts_2t^{-1}$.

Comment: The subgroup you are looking for may not exist. Let $H=\langle s_2,\ldots,s_n\mid R\rangle$. As @YCor mentioned, your group is just $G=H*\langle t\rangle$ (since the generator $s_1$ only appears once in one relator, and so can be eliminated).  Since you haven't told us anything about $H$, it could be a subgroup without proper finite-index subgroups. (Indeed, it could be the trivial group!)  You're looking for a finite-index subgroup $G_0$ of $G$ that contains $t$. But if $H$ doesn't have proper finite-index subgroups then $G_0$ must also contain $H$, so $G_0=G$.

Comment: The moral of my previous comment is that, at the very least, you probably need to assume that $H$ is residually finite and that $s_2$ has infinite order in $H$ (or at least that the order of $s_2$ is somehow compatible with $m$).  In this case, what you want is probably true, but it would help if you could clarify what you mean by " $t$ only acts on $s_1^m$". Do you mean that $s_1^i\notin G_0$ for $1\leq i<m$?

Comment: @HJRW Yes, $M$ is a finite index subgroup of a tree group (right-angled Artin group), but I don't know if $M$ is a RAAG again. I'm quite confused with the fact that I have obtained that $M$ is a free product, since otherwise my RAAG would be a free product, which is a contradiction...

Comment: @Karen it's hard to interpret your comment without knowing what you mean by $M$. Why don't you want $s_1$ to appear in $R$?

Comment: @Karen, I guess $M$ is what I called $H$?  Two things are certainly true: a finite-index subgroup of a tree group need not be a RAAG; and a finite-index subgroup of a tree group doesn't split freely.  If I had to *guess* what the problem was, I would guess that, when passing to a finite-index subgroup, you may not have "remembered" all the lifts of some of your elements. It's quite easy to accidentally get a free product that way.

Comment: @HJRW I think that I have solved my misunderstanding. I will edit the post completely explaining it better, I'm very sorry. Thanks for your answers

Comment: @Karen: I'm still a bit confused about your set-up. (You seem to be using the symbol "$*$" in a quite nonstandard way!) However, if all you want is a finite-index subgroup of $M$ that contains $s_1^m$ but not $s_1$, then this exists: $M$ is a 3-manifold group, and Hamilton proved that abelian subgroups of 3-manifold groups (eg $\langle s_1^m\rangle$) are separable; see Hamilton, Emily, Abelian subgroup separability of Haken 3-manifolds and closed hyperbolic $n$-orbifolds, *PLMS*.

Comment: @HJRW sorry, why is $M$ a $3$-manifold group?

Comment: Well, tree groups are 3-manifold groups (see, for instance, p. 234 of  Behrstock & Neumann, "Quasi-isometric classification of graph manifold groups", Duke).  Since $M$ is a finite-index subgroup of your tree group $G$, it follows that $M$ is the fundamental group of a finite cover of a 3-manifold, which is also a 3-manifold.

Comment: @HJRW ah ok yes! I forgot that tree groups are 3-manifold groups... However, I'd obtain that a power of $t$ lies in that finite index subgroup, but I would like $t$ to be a generator of that finite index subgroup... I want $t$ to have relations only with $s_{1}^m$ in the finite index subgroup, so that it is still an HNN extension with stable letter $t$.

Comment: To do that, you need to check that the subgroup $\langle s_1^m,t\rangle$ is separable and doesn't contain $s_1$. If I've understood the set-up correctly, $\langle s_1,t\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$, in which case this follows again from Hamilton's theorem.